# Gmp apparently not working under MinGW

Tags: gcc, mingw, gmp

I struggled during the whole afternoon with GMP and Mingw, and after a HUGE number of tries I made to install it. Actually, what I did is: installing a fresh brand new copy of MinGW (32 bit, standard latest version, downloaded from sourceforge), selecting the msys component during installation, and then using msys to install GMP from sources. 
1) I downloaded sources from the home page of the gmplib official website (just the standard source release, link in the upper part of the home page).
2) I extracted it into some location reachable from msys.
3) I did the "./configure" step
4) Then the "make" step
5) Then "make install"
6) Then "make check".
No problems, it looked like it was just working. I tried to compile this under gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mpz_t a, b;                       /* working numbers */
  return 0;
}
```

It compiled without any error. But then, when I try to add:

```
mpz_init(a);
```

right under the declaration of a, gcc prints out:

C:\Users\MATTEO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6wXtx9.o:gmptest.c:(.text+0x1c): undefine
d reference to `__gmpz_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Do you know anything about this error? Can anybody help me? Thank you very much!

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but did you include "-lgmp" to tell the compiler to link to the gmp library?